# OP edited duplicate question; now it's a duplicate of another question. What do I do?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018156/a-beginner-concept-on-github) as duplicate. My flag was marked as helpful, but the question wasn't closed because OP edited and it is no longer a duplicate of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493396/git-master-branch-has-no-upstream-branch) I flagged it for. However, it is now a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328800/github-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-h). As I already flagged the question as duplicate, I cannot add another flag.

What is the best way to deal with this? My ideas:

- Add a comment to point OP to the other duplicate. However, this wouldn't gain a mod's attention and the question wouldn't be closed.
- Flag the question as "in need of moderator intervention".

More generally: Would it make sense to allow a second duplicate flag in this case, i.e. if the first flag was helpful but the question wasn't closed because it was edited?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Add a comment to point OP to the other duplicate. However, this wouldn't gain a mod's attention and the question wouldn't be closed.

Mods virtually never look at close flags to begin with.  it's just there for other members of the community.  But by all means comment.

> Flag the question as "in need of moderator intervention".

A mod is just going to decline such a flag.  You shouldn't be flagging posts to mods for closure; as has already been said, flags for closure aren't something mods deal with at all.

Comment: So the solution is to just add a comment, hope the OP takes the correct action or that someone else flags?

Comment: @Tas not necessary OP - comment is useful for others to close as duplicate (searching for duplicate is hard, VTC is easy). This is especially true if gold-hammer holder visits such question.

Comment: @Tas Flagging as a duplicate isn't doing much more than adding a comment in the first place, really.